# Pandas: Looping Crosstabs to return a single crosstab for every combination in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array of 1, 2, and empty values each with a different column header. The goal is to create single crosstabs for each combination of columns, for example, the crosstab between Var1 and Var2 currently shows:
Var1 1.0  2.0

Var2
1.0 188    7

2.0 13   23

and this is running currently using the following code:
pd.crosstab(df.Var1, df.Var2)), which is the intended format.

However, I cannot understand how to run a loop which calculates each crosstab for every combination of columns. Please can you advise?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas loop to run multiple cross tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67920513/pandas-loop-to-run-multiple-cross-tabs)

Comment: it does - thank you!